# What do the numbers in parentheses mean?

Tags: gosu

In Gosu (Goblin Supremacy), what do the numbers in parentheses on each card's description indicate?  For example:

```
(Justice) When Justice comes into play draw 3(+1) cards.
```

We had been playing that the player with the Advantage token got to do the () actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the bonus if at least one other player has more victory points than you. I'm basing that on the description at the end of this unofficial [rules summary](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/59745/gosu-1-page-rules-summary-english).

The [official rulebook is available online](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/59520/gosu-english-rules-pdf), but I seem to be missing the font for the text, so I can't read it to confirm.